# Retrieve all list items assigned to me across all lists on a site

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, task-list, task-assignment

Approaching Sharepoint Lists with more imaginative power than competence, I expected that the intention of the Assigned To field would be connected to and reflected in  the "Assigned to me" task list in ToDo/Planner, which I see isn't the case.

I have searched and found different Flow solutions to mimic this, but there must be some (to me) hidden complexity involved since this feature is not implemented "under the hood" so to speak.

How can I most effectively (as an end user) get a view of list of Sharepoint List items assigned to me across a site?

What am I (or Microsoft) missing since this functionality doesn't appear to be  a commodity feature?

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. SharePoint tries to be all things to all people and as a result a lot of things seem half baked. Aggregating things across sites and/or lists is a common pain point.

I'm assuming that what you have is a number of different task lists that you need to monitor, and that you're looking for a purely end-user solution.

You could use Search for this. You should have a Search Center set up at `https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/search`

Enter a query for items where the Assigned To field is equal to your name, such as:

`AssignedTo:"Derek Gusoff"`

You should get a list of all tasks where that criteria is true. You will also get completed tasks, which maybe you don't want, in which case you'd add a condition where Task Status is not equal to Completed (the `<>` is a "not equal" operator):

`StatusOWSCHCS<>"Completed" AssignedTo:"Derek Gusoff"`

We're using the names of SharePoint Managed Search properties, which you don't need to know, but it explains why the terms are as they are.

You might want to find all tasks with a certain status, say "In Progress":

`StatusOWSCHCS:"In Progress" AssignedTo:"Derek Gusoff"`

Finally, you might want to restrict your search to show only items with the Content Type of "Task" in case you have other types of lists out there:

`StatusOWSCHCS:"In Progress" AssignedTo:"Derek Gusoff" ContentType:Task`

The Search Center is incredibly useful for end users if you know how to use it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference

**NOTE**: Search does not update in real time. Most of the time the indexes catch up within 15 minutes or so, but this being SharePoint...

Comment: Thanks a lot, this opens a new world to me, not the least the fact that the search engine can be accessed through a REST API.